# What is best word to shout "hide him in safe place"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

A leader is delivering a talk on a dais and one of the security officers finds a threat to him and shouts from the distance to alert the leader or other security officers around him. What is best word or phrase he should use to alert them to be safe. I need a word like "crouch" or tuck him down"

Comment: Would '*Get Down!*' or '*Take Cover!*' do the trick?

Comment: *Protect*? *Hide*? *Conceal*?